# PDO statement error for "SUM"

Tags: sql, pdo

I have a query that im trying to collect tallys from fields in one query to avoid querying 4 times i added them all into one query.

But i am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

           ')) as english,
            sum(if(class='2')) as science,
            sum(if(class='3')) as french 
            F' at line 3
```

I'm not sure how the syntax is meant to be for this so was hopeing some one might know... my query is this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 
            count(id) AS total, 
            sum(if(class=?)) as english,
            sum(if(class=?)) as science,
            sum(if(class=?)) as french 
            FROM school");

    try{
        $stmt->execute(array(1,2,3));
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e -> getMessage();  exit;
    }
```

Does any one know the correct syntax for this ?

Comment: Additional: i got this syntax attempt from reading this:
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/360574/multiple-count-queries-in-one-query-#post1540069
But didn't work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, you have missed a right bracket in each sum line.

Then, Im not sure about if(..,..,..) statement, I usually write CASE WHEN (condition) THEN expr1 ELSE expr2 END

Comment: Now your "if" looks very weird and i can't even understand what do you want... May be you are trying to get result of this? :
`sum(CASE WHEN (class=?) THEN 1 else 0 END) as english,
sum(CASE WHEN (class=?) THEN 1 else 0 END) as science,
sum(CASE WHEN (class=?) THEN 1 else 0 END) as french`

Comment: Isn't a CASE just an alternative to the IF method?

Comment: Actualy it is in your case, but IF can handle only THEN and ELSE, whereas with CASE you can write many WHEN conditions and one else, something like `CASE
    WHEN d = 'I' THEN 1
    WHEN d = 'II' THEN 2
    WHEN d = 'III' THEN 3
    else 0
  end `